# My app crashed for unknown reason when I tried to setOnClickListener for a button in ListView

Tags: android, listview, button

I'm building a Contact app using ListView. My ListView has 2 button. In this app, to test the respond ability of the buttons, I intended to set the button "Edit" so that when I click on it, it will change to "Clicked", and the button "Delete" will change to "Clicked", too. When I ran the Debug, the app stopped working and I couldn't get it work again (before I added the onClickListener, this app had worked property).

I don't know what is the error, and have tried many ways to fix.

Here is my row_listview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_margin="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/if_male3_403019" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Akai Shuichi"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="0982xxxxxx"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.3"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#3FE0FF"
            android:onClick="myClickHandler"
            android:text="Edit"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#F73131"
            android:onClick="myClickHandler"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.huy9515gmail.mycontact;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.edt_inputName) EditText edtName;
    @BindView(R.id.btnAdd) Button btnAdd;
    @BindView(R.id.btnEdit) Button btnEdit;
    @BindView(R.id.btnDelete) Button btnDelete;
    @BindView(R.id.edt_inputNumber) EditText edtNumber;
    @BindView(R.id.rdbtn_male) RadioButton rdbtn_male;
    @BindView(R.id.rdbtn_female) RadioButton rdbtn_female;
    @BindView(R.id.rdbtn_others) RadioButton rdbtn_others;
    @BindView(R.id.gender) RadioGroup genderSelection;
    private ListView lvContact;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    lvContact = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_contact);
    final ArrayList<Contact> arrContact = new ArrayList<>();

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //validating contact info
            if (((edtName.getText().toString().trim()) == "") || (edtNumber.getText().toString().trim() == "") || ((rdbtn_male.isChecked()==false) && (rdbtn_female.isChecked()==false) &&(rdbtn_others.isChecked()==false))) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid contact info! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //adding contact info
            else {
                Contact contact = new Contact(Gender.male, "", "");

                //adding info
                contact.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
                contact.setNumber(edtNumber.getText().toString());

                arrContact.add(contact);
            }

            CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row_listview, arrContact);
            lvContact.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
    });
}

public void myClickHandler(View v) {
    LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
    Button btnEdit = (Button) vwParentRow.getChildAt(0);
    Button btnDelete = (Button) vwParentRow.getChildAt(1);

    btnEdit.setText("Clicked");
    btnDelete.setText("Clicked");
}
}
```

And here is the row_listview.xml layout:

[image: row_listview.xml layout]

Comment: Anything in logcat?

Comment: Well.....I've just pressed Alt+6 and it popped up a window with numerous code line @@

Comment: Butdo you see any exception?

Comment: It appears like this:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.huy9515gmail.mycontact, PID: 4035
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'btnEdit' with ID 2131427456 for field 'btnEdit' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the `android:onClick` in XML, do the same as you did for `btnAdd`.

Find the view by id or use butterknife, then put the following in `onCreate()`

```
btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Your code here
        }
    });
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Your code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm worrying that, in example, my ListView has about 100+ contact info, that means it will have 200+ buttons in total. Will this work for every ListView rows?

Comment: Yes.  Setting listeners programmatically is the defacto standard.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an element in your XML file with the id like this:

`android:id="@+id/btnAdd"`

Comment: I added the ID at both of the "Edit" and "Delete" buttons in xml file. And the "Add" is, too